# Use of comma before 'next' in a question

Tags: grammaticality, commas

Is the comma correctly placed in this sentence?

"What will he do, next?"

I believe the comma is incorrect and should be deleted. Is this right?

Comment: What will he do tomorrow? What will he do next? What will he do now?

Comment: It really depends if you want to express a pause, at that moment, or not. After all, that is the purpose of a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, delete.

Next is used as an adverb here, placed after the verb. No commas between verb and adverb.

*Run quickly.
Read now.
Do next.*